# SpringTemplateEngine setRenderHiddenMarkersBeforeCheckboxes method did not exist

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am creating a web application with SpringBoot and Thymeleaf layouts. Once I start the application, I get the following error while using Thymeleaf.

```
The following method did not exist:
 
    org.thymeleaf.spring5.SpringTemplateEngine.setRenderHiddenMarkersBeforeCheckboxes(Z)V
```

My POM :

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.2.0.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.9.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.4.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>
...
<dependency>
   ...  
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf-layout-dialect</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Java Config :

```
@Bean
public LayoutDialect layoutDialect() {
    return new LayoutDialect();
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Turned out to be a version issue. Solved it by changing the `thymeleaf.version` to `thymeleaf-spring5.version` in `properties`

```
<properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <!--<thymeleaf.version>3.0.9.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>-->
        <thymeleaf-spring5.version>3.0.9.RELEASE</thymeleaf-spring5.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.4.1</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
</properties>
```